# Omit sources partially in Leiningen

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I've got an API that I need to export, but a lot of code that I would like to keep from prying eyes. If I include :omit-sources true, then all of the codebase disappears, and my API is no longer available to compile against.

How could this be achieved? I will try to use git submodules, but I wonder if there is an alternative approach compatible with my current project layout, as in, exclude everything but a package.

Edit: I've got a data_readers.clj that won't make it into the JAR if I use :omit-sources

What I currently do is include
:filespecs [{:type :bytes :path "data_readers.clj"
                                     :bytes ~(slurp "src/main/shared/clj/data_readers.clj")}]

to include the file manually, but this causes trouble in the Cursive IntelliJ plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need both `:aot` (ahead-of-time compilation) and `:omit-source`.

When `:aot` is not used (that's the default), clojure will try to compile the classes on the fly from the sources in the jar, so it needs the sources.

You can use `:aot :all`, or `:aot [my.awesome.api]` if you are going to expose just your api ns.

So your project.clj will look like:

`(defproject my-project ...
  ...
  :aot :all
  :omit-source true)`

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#%21topic/clojure/atHQKVLhT6E) from the clojure mailing list has info about this. Also the [compilation page in clojure.org](http://clojure.org/compilation) explains the ahead-of-time compilation very well:

> Clojure compiles all code you load on-the-fly into JVM bytecode, but
>   sometimes it is advantageous to compile ahead-of-time (AOT). Some
>   reasons to use AOT compilation are:
>
> - To deliver your application without source
> - To speed up application startup
> - To generate named classes for use by Java
> - To create an application that does not need runtime bytecode generation and custom classloaders

Comment: Thanks @nberger. I believe, however, that :omit-source would still omit all sources from the JAR, independently of whether which of those were compiled in :aot.

Comment: `data_readers.clj` is a very specific case, I'd say it's not part of the api your lib exports but it's sugar to make consuming your api easier. Your question didn't mention data_readers.clj. When it starts, clojure [reads this file](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7453) as if it was a resource, so you can perfectly put it in `resources/data_readers.clj` and it [will be included in the jar](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/jar.clj#L206) even with `:omit-source true`.

Comment: To show an example, [honeysql](https://github.com/jkk/honeysql/blob/master/resources/data_readers.clj) includes its data_readers.clj in this way.

Comment: Thanks, including data_readers.clj in resources dir and adding :resource-paths ["resources"] works. I swear I had tried it.